# PHP Variable showing {}

Tags: php

I wonderd if theres a way you can do this ive seen it on some other php scripting where you do a variable like below

```
<?php //variable as {name} $name = "Jake"; ?>
```

and you can show it by typing {name} or something like that if you include the file with php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: It's common for templating engines. Smarty, for example, will replace instances of {variable} if it corresponds to a variable set in the controller. But you have to either use an existing engine or write it yourself. It's not terribly complicated though

Comment: are you talking about templating, or are you referring to the way PHP interpolates complex variables in double-quoted strings (e.g. `echo "my object property is {$obj->prop}";`)?

Comment: Im new to php and not sure what i mean, i just seen it and thoughtit was cool, im sue its called template engine ill look up a tutorial on it thanks for the ideas

Answer (score 1):

Smarty Templates is good, but if you don't want to worry about including 3rd party libraries, and you are in control of your php.ini settings (to enable the short_open_tags directive), you can use short tags to do stuff like:

```
<p>Here's some html... hello <?= $dynamicName; ?>, how are you today?</p>
```

or

```
<? foreach($someArray as $val) : ?>
    <div><?= $val; ?></div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```